# how to take first and last observation in groupby in pandas and dcast the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  Date          time         tank        stock
  01-01-2018    05:30:00     1           4567
  01-01-2018    03:30:00     1           2345
  01-01-2018    04:30:00     1           1234
  01-01-2018    08:00:00     1           3345
  02-01-2018    06:30:00     2           4489
  02-01-2018    03:30:00     2           1290
  02-01-2018    11:30:00     2           6578
  02-01-2018    10:00:00     2           3444
```

I want to sort the dataframe with date,time and tank and then take first and last observation from stock.

```
 Sorted Dataframe

  Date          time         tank        stock
  01-01-2018    03:30:00     1           2345
  01-01-2018    04:30:00     1           1234
  01-01-2018    08:00:00     1           3345
  01-01-2018    05:30:00     1           4567
  02-01-2018    03:30:00     2           1290
  02-01-2018    06:30:00     2           4489
  02-01-2018    10:00:00     2           3444
  02-01-2018    11:30:00     2           6578

  Desired dataframe

  Date          tank    first_stock    last_stock
  01-01-2018    1       2345           4567
  02-01-2018    2       1290           6578
```

For sorting I am using following script in python

```
 df = df.groupby(['Date','tank']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['time'],ascending = True))
```

But,how to get the final dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with specify all 3 columns and then aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) 
and 
[`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values(['Date','tank', 'time'])
        .groupby(['Date','tank'])['stock']
        .agg(['first','last'])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
         Date  tank  first  last
0  01-01-2018     1   2345  3345
1  02-01-2018     2   1290  6578
```

Detail:

```
print (df.sort_values(['Date','tank', 'time']))
         Date      time  tank  stock
1  01-01-2018  03:30:00     1   2345
2  01-01-2018  04:30:00     1   1234
0  01-01-2018  05:30:00     1   4567
3  01-01-2018  08:00:00     1   3345
5  02-01-2018  03:30:00     2   1290
4  02-01-2018  06:30:00     2   4489
7  02-01-2018  10:00:00     2   3444
6  02-01-2018  11:30:00     2   6578
```